# How to split record in multiple records from start/end date record

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to split record to multiple record from start/end date in Oracle
I have data like this

`MachineID | start date        | end date          | running time |
 WC01      | 2019/09/05 07:00  | 2019/09/07 09:00  |     26:00    |`

and I want to split record to each day from 08:00 to 08:00

`MachineID | running date      |   running time   |
 WC01      | 2019/09/05        |        1:00      |
 WC01      | 2019/09/06        |       24:00      |
 WC01      | 2019/09/07        |        1:00      |`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does 6th September show 24 hours if you are only counting 8am to 8pm?

Comment: With your input, the time interval between start_date and end_date is 50 hours, not 26. How are you getting 26?

Answer (score 1):

We can handle this via the help from a calendar table which contains all dates you expect to appear in your data set, along with a separate record for each minute:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-05 00:00:00' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(rownum, 'MINUTE') AS dt
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level <= 5000
)

SELECT
    m.MachineID,
    TRUNC(d.dt) AS running_date,
    COUNT(t.MachineID) / 60 AS running_hours
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT MachineID FROM yourTable) m
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON d.dt >= t.start_date AND d.dt < t.end_date
WHERE
    TO_CHAR(d.dt, 'HH24') >= '08' AND TO_CHAR(d.dt, 'HH24') < '21'
GROUP BY
    m.MachineID,
    TRUNC(d.dt)
ORDER BY
    TRUNC(d.dt);
```

[image: screen capture of result set]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query:

```
SELECT
    MACHINEID,
    RUNNING_DATE,
    DECODE(RUNNING_DATE, TRUNC(START_DATE), CASE
        WHEN DIFF_START < 0  THEN 0
        WHEN DIFF_START > 12 THEN 12
        ELSE DIFF_START
    END, TRUNC(END_DATE), CASE
        WHEN DIFF_END < 0  THEN 0
        WHEN DIFF_END > 12 THEN 12
        ELSE DIFF_END
    END, 24) AS RUNNING_HOURS
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MACHINEID,
            RUNNING_DATE,
            ROUND(24 *((TRUNC(START_DATE + LVL - 1) + 8 / 24) - START_DATE)) AS DIFF_START,
            ROUND(24 *(END_DATE -(TRUNC(START_DATE + LVL - 1) + 8 / 24))) AS DIFF_END,
            START_DATE,
            END_DATE
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    DISTINCT MACHINEID,
                    LEVEL   AS LVL,
                    START_DATE,
                    END_DATE,
                    TRUNC(START_DATE + LEVEL - 1) AS RUNNING_DATE
                FROM
                    YOURTABLE
                CONNECT BY
                    LEVEL <= TRUNC(END_DATE) - TRUNC(START_DATE) + 1
            )
    );
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c589369235f1e454fd3eb53715e4e34)

Change the logic wherever it is not meeting your requirement. I have created the query taking sample data and expected output into consideration.

Cheers!!